How to separate acid and base streams in water electrolysis
I am very new to chemistry and am trying to figure out how to separate the acid-base streams in standard water electrolysis. Namely, I want to end up with two streams, one of OH-1 ions and one of H+ ions.
I believe a two-compartment electrolyzer but am wondering exactly what that is and how I could get one relatively cheaply.
Thanks in advance, Arlo

To separate acid and base streams in water electrolysis, you can use a two-compartment electrolyzer. It has two chambers separated by a membrane:

Anode (positive side): Produces $ \text{H}^+ $ ions (acidic).
Cathode (negative side): Produces $ \text{OH}^- $ ions (basic).

You can DIY with two containers, graphite or stainless steel electrodes, and a membrane (e.g., Nafion or a salt bridge). Or, buy a small educational electrolyzer online for a low-cost option. This setup will give you separate acidic and basic streams.
That's the basic concept ,but achieving complete separation depends on the specific materials and setup used.

Thanks Antony! I am just wondering if it matters which membrane I use for this. You mentioned that achieving complete separation depends on the setup/materials but what happens if it is not complete, does that mean it’s just more diluted (with water)? Also, could you recommend any specific cheap electrolyzers that would work? Finally, do I need to add an electrolyte for the electrolysis to work? Thanks so much in advance, Arlo

What is "standard electrolysis" ? Which electrolyte do you use ? Please don't try with sodium chloride ? Prefer sodium sulfate. Anyway you may obtain two separated currents, one of an acidic solution, and the other of a basic solution. But both will contain much more original solute in the obtained acidic or basic solution.
